# Should I use domain module in for node js >4v?

Tags: node.js

As I know domain module has been deprecated. So shall I use it in my project that has node js version > 4v ? And if no, is there any alternative module that handles exception as domain does ?

Answer (score 0):

Domain was never quite stable. It's better to handle the errors you can handle and restart the app for those you can't

Comment: and how should i handle those erros using domain model or?

Comment: No, use process.on('uncaughtException')